# Fastest way to create CRUD in Liferay 6.1

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I want to create a liferay portlet that can do Create , Read, Update and Delete records.

Is there any fastest way to achived that? 
I read about vaadin ang gwt and it is hard for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this: [xmlportletfactory](http://xmlportletfactory)

I am using it and it is really helpful.

[Here](http://www.xmlportletfactory.org/examples) are code example

Answer (score 0):

xmlportletfactory is a good way as well.

Also using JSF is a fast way to have a crud frontend.

[Wiki page for JSF development](https://www.liferay.com/it/documentation/liferay-portal/6.2/development/-/ai/develop-jsf-portlets-with-liferay-faces-liferay-portal-6-2-dev-guide-en)